Solana Pay on Wordpress or React?
I’m building a simple website via Wordpress and React. Curious if Solana Pay works on Wordpress or React?
We want to accept Solana as a payment.
Thank You!

Yes, Solana Pay works on React. Checkout their docs here:
https://docs.solanapay.com/
As far as React, here is a Nextjs example project from solana-pay.
https://github.com/anza-xyz/solana-pay/tree/master/examples/point-of-sale
It shows you how payment flow should operate.
